# How to use formula correctly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was watching a induction video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFqna5F0kW8&list=PL6iY5UTqVJ7ju1l1592l5zhUb1yECit6O&index=7&t=57s)

And I got a question about this formula:

[image]

When I use `n = 1` for the basis step then we can see that the answer is `4` in the above screenshot.

But when I use `n = 2` then I would expect the answer is `9`. Which is indeed `9` on the left hand side but not the on right hand side:

$$
(5\cdot 2-1)= \frac{2}{2}\cdot (3+5\cdot 2)
$$
$$
9 = 13
$$

Does someone has any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's $4 + 9 = 13$ on the left hand side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side's result is most certainly not $9$ for $n=2$. For $n=2$, the left hand side is equal to $$4+9=13$$ which is what the right hand side is equal to.

For $n=3$, for exmaple, the left hand side is equal to $$4+9+14,$$ for $n=4$, it is $$4+9+14+19$$

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

With $n=2$ we have

$$\overbrace{4+9}^{\text{2 terms}}=\frac 2 2(3+5\cdot 2)=13$$

Answer (score 0):

$$4+9+14+...+(5n-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(5i-1)$$

So when $n=2$ you have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2}(5i-1)=4+9=13.$$